# Cache bust custom task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am writing a custom VS extension that contains a Azure DevOps custom build task. I am following the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts

Here are the steps I follow:

1. Publish a new version of my extension (say 0.1.4)
2. Uninstall and reinstall the extension in a test organization
3. Update a Pipeline to use the custom task provided by extension
4. Run Pipeline

The issue is that a previous cached version of the custom task (0.1.0) is used. How do I force Pipelines to use the custom task from the new version (0.1.4)?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. I suspect that if you change only the version patch it ignores and maintains the task cache. But if you change the minor or major the task is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The extension's version number (from `vss-extension.json`) is independent from the task's version number (from `task.json`).

Azure Pipelines will use the latest minor/patch version for a given major version of the **task** independent of the extension version number.

No need to uninstall/reinstall the extension - everything works automatically after you publish a new minor/patch version for the task.